# Site.com HTML tag Class

Tags: site.com

I'm trying to replicate an html site inside of Site.com, however, I'm running into this issue:

The site I'm replicating, currently has a bunch of css classes applied to the "html" element of the page. I can see how to add classes to the "body" tag of the page quite easily, but was wondering how I get these html classes in?

If anyone knows how to do that I would be very grateful for the information.

Comment: If htm customization fails, you could use simple js/jquery snippet to add class attribute to html node:

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){ $('html').addClass('myClassName');});

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this, as with most style sheet editing in site.com. First create a css style sheet, and attach it to your page via the Style Sheets select tools. Then either:

1. You can create a new rule based on "html." You can then add rules from all the classes attached to your html element.
2. You can alternatively click the "Edit Style Sheet Code" button above your style sheet. And there you can even copy and paste in classes from your old page if you would like.